# How can I re-rank hierarchical data without a loop?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

I'm attempting to re-rank nodes in a hierarchical data set. This is structured as you would expect. A menu item would have a parent menu item, but in this case... I'm taking about n number of menu items underneath one parent. If I move a menu item from position 10 to position 5 like such:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6  7 8 9 10 <-- Original
1 2 3 4 5 10 6 7 8 9  <-- New
```

Is there a way to do this in one operation versus looping through the set and comparing the new position to the existing positions? I thought I saw some RANK functionality that would do this, but I can't seem to find it.

UPDATE: Here's how it is structured:

```
MENUID, PARENTID, SORT_RANK
1       100       1
2       100       2
3       100       3
4       100       4
5       100       5
```

If I move MENUID 5 up three positions, it would sit between 2 and 3, I want to update the sort rank. Is there a way to do this without grabbing the parentID structure and looping through all records.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this data is hierarchically structured. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @VincentMalgrat Take a look now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind.

The first is to change the SORT_RANK for the moving item to the average of the preceding and following items, so if you want to move the item with MENUID=5 so it's between MENUID 2 and MENUID 3 you'd set the SORT_RANK for MENUID=5 to 2.5.  So, something like the following:

```
UPDATE MENU_TABLE
  SET SORT_RANK = ((SELECT SORT_RANK FROM MENU_TABLE WHERE MENUID = 2) + 
                   (SELECT SORT_RANK FROM MENU_TABLE WHERE MENUID = 3)) / 2
  WHERE MENUID = 5;
```

In this manner you'd end up with MENUID's with non-integer values, but they'd still sort properly.

The second would be to do the following:

```
UPDATE MENU_TABLE
  SET SORT_RANK = SORT_RANK + 1
  WHERE PARENTID = 100 AND
        SORT_RANK > 2;

UPDATE MENU_TABLE
  SET SORT_RANK = 3
  WHERE MENUID = 5;
```

However, this latter method requires two statements which may not be what you're looking for.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the fact that the data is structured in a hierarchy matters.

You could update your order with a single query. Assuming item at `rank_order` `:R_START` goes to place `:R_STOP`:

```
SQL> variable r_start NUMBER
SQL> variable r_stop NUMBER
SQL> EXEC :r_start := 5; :r_stop := 3;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> UPDATE mytable
  2     SET sort_rank = CASE WHEN sort_rank = :R_START  THEN :R_STOP
  3                      ELSE sort_rank + sign(:R_START - :R_STOP)
  4                      END
  5   WHERE parentid = 100
  6     AND sort_rank BETWEEN LEAST(:R_START, :R_STOP)
  7                       AND GREATEST(:R_START, :R_STOP);

3 rows updated

SQL> select * from mytable order by sort_rank;

    MENUID   PARENTID  SORT_RANK
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100          1
         2        100          2
         5        100          3
         3        100          4
         4        100          5
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer your question with a question; why are you mandating that your `SORT_RANK` field consist of integers?

If the `SORT_RANK` field is just a `NUMBER`, not a `NUMBER(10,0)`, you can move any item to any position anywhere without re-ranking problem.